# Is there anything I can do to reduce the runtime of this program?

Tags: loops, pascal

```
uses sysutils;
var
stringlength,querynum,i,start,tail,j,cnt:int64;
input,temp:ansistring;
querychar:char;
begin
readln(stringlength,querynum);
readln(input);
for i:=1 to querynum do begin
   readln(querychar,start,tail);
   temp:=copy(input,start,tail-start+1);
   writeln(temp.CountChar(querychar));
end;
end.
```

This is a program for finding how many times a character occurs during a certain segment of a string. The input format is first line input the length of the string and the number of queries(n), then the next n lines are input the character to search for its occurence, and the section of the string (eg from 3 to 8). Sometimes the runtime for the program is very high, which I think is due to the for loop. Is there any way I could reduce the runtime?

Comment: what language? if the code works, code review might be a better place to ask this sort of question

Comment: This code is pascal

Comment: At a glance the most time-consuming piece seems to be the copying of the substring. You could eliminate that and loop over `input` directly from `start` to `tail`, counting the characters that match the query.

Answer (score 0):

[Speed usually goes at the expense of memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space%E2%80%93time_tradeoff).
If you want to gain speed, you can transform your data into a form/layout that can be even faster processed than the input.
In particular sets are suitable to achieve your goal.

Now, this is an *implementation detail*.
Pascal – the programming language – does *not* prescribe any memory layout.
Unlikely as it may be, your processor could theoretically produce even worse results when using a set.
I therefore generally recommend using the most maintainable algorithm.
Your algorithm already satisfies this criterion quite well.

```pascal
program characterSubstringOccurrences(input, output);
    type
        { `integer`-prefix to facilitate sorting in documentation tools. }
        integerNonNegative = 0..maxInt;
    
    {
        Performs specified number of character queries on sample.
        
        \param sample the sample to inspect for a certain character
        \param queryCount the total number of queries to prompt
    }
    procedure processQueries(
            protected sample: string;
            queryCount: integerNonNegative
        );
        type
            sampleIndex = 1..sample.capacity;
            sampleIndices = set of sampleIndex;
        var
            c: char;
            i, j: sampleIndex;
            characterIndex: array[char] of sampleIndices value [otherwise []];
```

This is a subroutine, because it trivializes the creation of sets with *non-constant* bounds (here the capacity of the given `sample`).
We simply need to declare our data types accordingly; no invocation of `new` necessary.

```pascal
        begin
            { --- analyze `sample` step --- }
            for i := 1 to length(sample) do
            begin
                characterIndex[sample[i]] := characterIndex[sample[i]] + [i];
            end;
            
            { --- draw conclusions from analysis step --- }
            for queryCount := 1 to queryCount do
            begin
                readLn(c, i, j);
                writeLn(card(characterIndex[c] * [i..j]));
            end;
        end;
```

Evidently this avoids re-inspecting the sample over and over again.
All you need to do is taking the cardinality of the intersection of [start, tail] with the set of indices specified character appears at.

```pascal
    { === MAIN ================================================== }
    var
        sample: ^string;
        sampleLength: integerNonNegative;
        queryCount: integerNonNegative;
    begin
        if EOF then
        begin
            writeLn('Error: Program needs input.');
            halt;
        end;
        
        read(sampleLength);
        if sampleLength = 0 then
        begin
            writeLn('Error: Sample length must be positive.');
            halt;
        end;
        
        new(sample, sampleLength);
        
        readLn(queryCount);
        readLn(sample^);
        
        if queryCount > 0 then
        begin
            processQueries(sample^, queryCount);
        end;
    end.
```

Now this is a `program` compliant to ISO standard 10206 “Extended Pascal”.
From your code’s non-standard deviations I gather you’re using some dialect, yet the general idea of extracting/transforming data into a form that’s faster to process remains.